# Select data from multiple tables with different names and fields names

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

In CMS Joomla I need to select data from table `#__adsmanager_ads`, column `ad_healine`, and from table `#__modules`, column `title`.

Then I need to check `if ad_headline == title` to load module (that equals ad_healine).

I use this code for a single table select:

```
<?php
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('ad_headline')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__adsmanager_ads'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($results),true); // Convert stdClass object to array
print_r($objectoarr);     
?>
```

=========================================================================
Next i write code below and problem is almost solver

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query 
    ->select (array('a.ad_headline', 'b.title')) //Select columns from database
    ->from ($db->quoteName('#__adsmanager_ads','a'))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__modules', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.ad_headline') . '=' . $db->quoteName('b.title').')');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($result),true); // Convert stdClass object to array

foreach ($objectoarr as $adhealine){
        if ($adhealine[ad_headline] === $adhealine[title])
        {
            $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
            $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
            $position   = 'inside-ad';
            $options   = array('style' => 'raw');
            echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null); 
        }
}
?>
```

But problem is that all modules set to position `inside-ad` loading there. But I need load only module which's name  equivalent to ads name.

How can i solve this problem? Thank in advance